# is Yii CFormModel rules deals with arrays

Tags: php, yii

can we make validations with arrays 
i.e.

```
$x="123@ex.com";
```

it's validation rule is

```
array("x","email");
```

how can we do the following:

```
$x=array("a1@ss.com","a2@ss.com","a3@ss.com");
//--------what the rule(s) should look like
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to make your own callback, in which you will check every email in the array.

Comment: yes my friend, i overloaded the method validate and added a call to function, thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use this validator instead of a custom function:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CRangeValidator